# Move java website to applet

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have create webapplication to manage company calendar.

After i've done it i realize, that it would be greate to open this application not by web browser, but as an Java application on computer.

Is there any possibility to move web application to java application which is run on computer ?

Everything base on Spring 3, hibernate 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using javaFX webview with minimum changes you can get a feel of desktop application for web clients

Please visit below link for more details
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm